# Django - pass URL as URL Parameter

Tags: python, django

I have the following URL pattern:

```
path('my_path/(?P<url>\w+)/$', views.my_view)
```

where `url` is a url such as https:www.google.com

It always says path not found.

What is the right way to pass an url as url parameter?

Comment: It looks like this is *not* related  to the URL, but even if you write an URL in a path, this will result in encoding all sorts of characters, so I do not know if that is a good idea. The `.` is for example *not* part of `\w`.

Comment: you have to URL-escape the url (e.g. replace colons and slashes by their escaped versions %3A and %2F). Also your pattern isn't going to match since \w only covers alphanumeric characters + underscore

Comment: It's hard to help because you haven't shown your view, and you have a mix of real and made up variable names. The `path()` doesn't include `format` so it's not clear why you'd get this in the error message. You shouldn't be using `(?P<url>\w+)` or `$` with `path()` - it doesn't use regexes.

Comment: sorry for that. What is the right way to match a url? or rather match everything after the slash?

Comment: See the `path()` docs for the correct way to use `path()`, and the list of path converters below that. If you want to match any characters including `/`, then you need `<path:url>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass url as query parameter instead of path parameter.